# How to upgrade postgresql using brew postgresql-upgrade-database

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

It appears there is a newish command `brew postgresql postgresql-upgrade-database` that can be used to assist in the upgrade a postgresql database group.  How do I use it to upgrade between major versions of postgresql, e.g. from `11.8` to `12`? Also between minor versions e.g. `11.6` to `11.8`?

Comment: I have encountered an issue, github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/60686, so will provide an answer when I have worked through that. However, in the meantime, before using the command, I advise a) backup up your database cluster d) make sure all postgresql processes ares stopped and c) do a brew update